# Cancel circled text under circledsteps?

Tags: cancel

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{cancel}


\begin{document}

\(\odot, \cancel\odot\)

\(\Circled{1}, \cancel\Circled{1}\)

\end{document}
```

How may one cancel `\(\Circled{1}\)` just as `\(\cancel\odot\)` cancels `\(\odot\)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose `\Circled{1}` in braces, otherwise you’re telling `\cancel` to pass just `\Circled` as an argument which gives an error:

```
\(\Circled{1}, \cancel{\Circled{1}}\)
```